# Change value of new Date() 's time

Tags: javascript

I am fetching the value of today's date using this code below:

```
var today = new Date();
console.log(today);
```

The value of console log is **Sat May 30 2020 12:13:18 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

But what I want to achieve is, whatever the time is I want value as

`var today_morning = Sat May 30 2020 09:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

How do I get this value in `today_morning` irrespective of what **time value** is in `var today`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)

```js
var today = new Date();
console.log(today.toString());

today.setHours(9, 30, 0)
var today_morning = today;
console.log(today_morning.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get day of week, month, date and year from today and append with the time string. 
You can use an array of names, and getMonth(), getDay()  to return the month and day as name:

```
var today = new Date();

var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

var today_morning = days[today.getDay()] + " " + months[today.getMonth()] + " " + today.getDate() + " " + today.getFullYear() + " 09:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"; 

console.log(today_morning);
```

This will print "Sat May 30 2020 09:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"